# Permanently redirect my old mobile site to new mobile friendly desktop full site?

Tags: .htaccess

I need to permanently redirect my old mobile site m.sdppm.com to https://www.sdppm.com using .htaccess. The reason being, I now have a responsive mobile friendly site and no longer need the m.sdppm.com site. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this simple rule to your .htaccess placed in your website's root directory.

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.sdppm\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.sdppm.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

As you can tell, the rule checks if `%{HTTP_HOST}` matches your old mobile site and redirects.